# Auto Complete TextBox Using ASP.NET jQuery AJAX call paste not working have to type each letter if not using autocomplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

> i have two auto complete text boxes which is ajax mvc based, email and mobile
> input box look like this(input boxes are appended wrapped ones on button click displyed (add contact button)).the problem is when i paste something,the box dissappear

```
                    ' </div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-3">' +
                    '<label class="control-label">Email Id</label>' +
                    '<div class="input-group">' +
                    '<select   name="LstContacts[' + rowno + '].EmailId" class="form-control select2 emailid" id="EmailId' + rowno + '" onchange="loadcontactemail(' + rowno + ',this)"></select>' +
```

> the jquery look like this,it has both email and mobile loading option which will fetch existing customer contact number and we can select it

````
    $('input[type="search"]').change(function () {

        var val = $(this).val()
        var reg = /^0/gi;
        if (val.match(reg)) {
            $(this).val(val.replace(reg, ''));
        }
    });
    function loadcontact(i, obj) {
        $('.mobilenumber').select2('destroy');
        var s = $("#Mobile" + i).val();
        s = s.replace(/^0+/, '');
        var opt = '<option value="' + s + '" selected>' + s + '</option>'
        $("#Mobile" + i).append(opt);
        mobileload();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/supplier/getcontactsbymobile",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { mobile: obj.value },
            success: function (result) {


                $("#firstname" + i).val(result[0].FirstName);
                $("#Website" + i).val(result[0].Website);
                $('.emailid').select2('destroy');
                var opt = '<option value="' + result[0].EmailId + '" selected>' + result[0].EmailId + '</option>'
                $("#EmailId" + i).append(opt);

                $("#EmailId" + i).val(result[0].EmailId);


                $("#Mobile" + i).val(result[0].MobileNum);
                $("#CountryID" + i).val(result[0].CountryID);
                $("#Name" + i).val(result[0].Name + "," + result[0].Address);
                $("#lastname" + i).val(result[0].LastName);
                $("#ContactTypeID" + i).val(result[0].ContactTypeID);



                emailload();


            }
        });
    }
    function loadcontactemail(i, obj) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/supplier/getcontactsbyemail",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { email: obj.value },
            success: function (result) {

                $("#firstname" + i).val(result[0].FirstName);
                $("#Website" + i).val(result[0].Website);
                $("#EmailId" + i).val(result[0].EmailId);
                $('.mobilenumber').select2('destroy');
                var opt = '<option value="' + result[0].MobileNum + '" selected>' + result[0].MobileNum + '</option>'
                $("#Mobile" + i).append(opt);

                //$("#Mobile" + i).val(result[0].MobileNum);
                $("#CountryID" + i).val(result[0].CountryID);
                $("#Name" + i).val(result[0].Name + "," + result[0].Address);
                $("#lastname" + i).val(result[0].LastName);
                $("#ContactTypeID" + i).val(result[0].ContactTypeID);

                mobileload();




            }
        });
    }
    function callselect() {
        mobileload();
        emailload();


    }
    function mobileload() {
        $('.mobilenumber').select2({
            tags: true,


            minimumInputLength: 0,
            ajax: {
                url: "/Customer/SearchMobilecontact",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 50,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term || "",
                        x: "All",
                        page: params.page || 0,
                    };
                },

                processResults: function (data, params) {



                    params.page = params.page || 1;

                    return {

                        results: data
                    };

                },
                cache: true
            },
        });
    }
    function emailload() {
        $('.emailid').select2({
            tags: true,


            minimumInputLength: 0,
            ajax: {
                url: "/Customer/SearchEmailcontact",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 50,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term || "",
                        x: "All",
                        page: params.page || 0,
                    };
                },

                processResults: function (data, params) {



                    params.page = params.page || 1;

                    return {

                        results: data
                    };

                },
                cache: true
            },
        });
    }

</script> ```
````